# Exclude help and plugin pages from autocmd pattern

Tags: vim, vi, autocmd, neovim

I want to write command like `autocmd BufAdd * if &filetype != 'help' | echo 'foo'`, but it didn't work. I've tried different options: `&l:filetype`, `&buftype`, `&l:buftype`; tried with toggled `filetype` setting, but nothing changed. Global command `autocmd BufAdd * echo 'bar'` worked everywhere includes help pages, and the same time `:echo &filetype` on help pages returns `help`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You are not telling us what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @romainl, my fault. I'm trying to write command which will perform some function when I create new buffer, only if this buffer is not help or plugin page. But test command with the "if &filetype != 'help'" has the same behavior as command without this part (both triggers on help pages), which is what I was trying to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because,

1. While in `BufAdd` the current buffer can be (and quite probably is) different from the matched buffer;
2. While in `BufAdd` the matched buffer may (and quite probably will) not have any `&filetype` set yet.

Note that normally one should hook into some specific FileType with `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xyz.vim` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I wrapped condition in timer_start for test, and got the behavior that I expected.